# Atomic database write with async task enqueue

Tags: asynchronous, queue, microservices, task, atomic

Today, it is a common practice (in microservice architecture) to segregate the user facing logic (Sync part) from backend processing (async apart)to enhance service throughput, reliability and user experience. For instance, in an e-commerce website, an order is accepted by first validating it and then storing it in the database, while promptly responding to the user. Subsequently, the order processing, such as fulfillment, is carried out asynchronously in the backend through an event-driven workflow service.

The asynchronous processing aspect is typically implemented as a queue-based processing system, like a task queue such as Celery.

Now, my question revolves around how to ensure the atomicity of order persistence and task enqueue. Without an atomic guarantee, several issues may arise:

- if the enqueue occurs after DB persistence. then if the serve crashes right after database persistence and before task enqueue, then that order might just stay unprocessed.
- if the enqueue occurs before DB persistence, and the task might be processed before DB commit, then the order might not be found in database.

I am interested in understanding the widely accepted industry solution for establishing asynchronous processing in scenarios like this.

P.S. It's worth noting that one could have a daemon process that periodically checks the database for new orders and enqueues them in the task queue. However, this approach is often considered an anti-pattern because it introduces unnecessary load on the database and essentially treats the database as a queue. Also this approach could get tricky if the database is distributed and sharded.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you two approaches :

- use Change Data Capture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture), which is a stream of events emitted by a database when operations are performed. For example,  PostgreSQL expose its Write-Ahead Logging mechanism (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-intro.html). By using something like Debezium (https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html), you can stream those events to a Kafka topic or a RabbitMQ queue.
- write first in your message queue, then consume the queue to update the database. You can respond to the user as soon as the message is written, and rely on the retry to be confident that the order will be written sooner or later into the database. That's what "eventually consistent" means. You have to deal with a potential conflict : you check your stock, you write a message for the order, and later the message is processed and the stock is updated. But in the meantime, the stock may have changed, and the order cannot be processed. Well, deal with it, because that would happen anyway even with perfect transactions ! Stock are not always reliable : some items may have been lost or stolen, or somebody made an error while doing the inventory, and the item you just sold is not there to be shipped. To compensate, you have the choice (you decide or your client decides) : refund the client, or wait for more stock to arrive and ship the due item.

Comment: Thanks! I also considered the second approach. However, this could impact the user experience because the user wouldn't receive immediate confirmation of a successful order.

Another approach I've been considering is, since we could only respond to users after the async task is successfully enqueued. then we could rely on clients to retry if the server encounters issues between writing to the database and enqueueing the task. As long as the service is idempotent, clients could then retry as needed. curious any potential drawbacks to this approach.

Comment: I've completed my answer about the second approach (which is the one I recommand). There was too many things to add to put it as a comment ;-)